# Python scipy кластеризация

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть массив точек как на картинке, как я могу кластеризовать его и посчитать количество отдельных объектов в моём массиве? В данном случае хочу увидеть цифру 3

Раньше использовал вот такой вот код, но на этом массиве он считает каждую точку как отдельный объект, как я могу настроить чувствительность кластеризации в scipy?

```
from scipy import ndimage

list_coord_a = np.array(list_coord)
h = 0.00001
arr = (list_coord_a + 1) / h
list_coord_a = np.int64(arr)

map_a = list_coord_a[:, :2]
min_value = np.min(map_a, axis=0)
map_a = map_a - min_value
image = np.zeros(np.max(map_a, axis=0) + 1, dtype=np.int32)
image[map_a[:, 0], map_a[:, 1]] = 1
label, n = ndimage.label(image, structure=np.ones((3, 3)))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Часть массива из 7000 точек:

```
[0.0789702838086786, 0.026726748654913795, -0.33899998664855957]
[0.07952999876630526, 0.026726748654913795, -0.33899998664855957]
[0.07985346391344544, 0.02664790970030836, -0.33799999952316284]
[0.0809695917179403, 0.02664790970030836, -0.33799999952316284]
[0.0789702838086786, 0.026166138141604005, -0.33899998664855957]
[0.07929540001119802, 0.026088952884101083, -0.33799999952316284]
[0.02954005788482236, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661]
[0.0301857766134246, -0.10526589892460925, -0.33799999952316284]
[0.030652883578558728, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661]
[0.03677342489410876, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661]
[0.02635707779177199, -0.1061379429995061, -0.33899998664855957]
[0.03297609612466172, -0.10638381255702381, -0.33799999952316284]
[0.03343494781289965, -0.10606907160123173, -0.3370000123977661]
```

upd. вид сверху
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

upd 13:38 23.06
"u235" помог написал скрипт, который строит триангулированые сетки по входным данным:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri

t = np.array(t)
points = t[:, :2]
x = points[:, 0]
y = points[:, 1]
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_aspect('equal')

max_radius = 0.02
triangles = triang.triangles

xtri = x[triangles] - np.roll(x[triangles], 1, axis=1)
ytri = y[triangles] - np.roll(y[triangles], 1, axis=1)
maxi = np.max(np.sqrt(xtri ** 2 + ytri ** 2), axis=1)
triang.set_mask(maxi > max_radius)

ax1.triplot(triang, color="red")
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А попробуйте в лоб, используя методы кластеризации. DBSCAN(), linkage(), OPTICS()

Comment: Почитайте вот этот вопрос и мой ответ, может подойдёт https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1297437/260769

Comment: @CrazyElf так тот вопрос я и задавал)  Но там массив одномерный и регулярный, а тут сетка нерегулярная. Нужна триангуляция мне кажется. Хотел узнать так ли это. А так прямо тот код запускал и он находит 2 объекта вместо 3х

Comment: @Leonid А, понял ))  Ну, можно с метриками поиграться, наверное. Кластеризация вообще понятие неоднозначное. На верхней картинке два кластера довольно близко друг к другу лежат, это наверное сбивает алгоритм с толку.

Comment: @CrazyElf да вот я и пытаюсь найти такую кластеризацию где можно указать размер пустой области вокруг объекта. Потому что вы говорите два кластера близко друг к другу, но по факту там расстояние больше чем они сами, буду думать, спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @Leonid Методов кластеризации очень много. И оценивать их можно тоже по-разному. Читайте https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html там дофига всего :)

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо! А такой вопрос, для чего нужен диапазон for i in range(2, 10):
    kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=i, random_state=1).fit(X) 2-10,? Это число кластеров которые мы ищем? А если мне надо найти 150 кластеров?

Comment: @Leonid Ну да. Но больше 10 уже `silouette_score` (или как его там) ругается, нужен другой метод определения правильного числа кластеров тогда.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, как раз он и ругается, буду другие смотреть по типу  тех что выше предлагали DBSCAN(), linkage(), OPTICS()

Comment: Только это про разное. Методы кластеризации - это одно, а метрика хорошести получившихся кластеров - это другое. `DBSCAN` и прочее - это собственно методы кластеризации. Как они отрабатывают - это ещё и глазами бы хорошо посмотреть.

Comment: @CrazyElf В данном конкретном случае глазками посмотреть - как раз просто. Три координаты всего. В общем-то -  почти классический случай. А если реальных объектов три, да они так хорошо разделены, как на картинке -  то вообще красота для таких методов. Тот-же DBSCAN способен сам обнаруживать количество кластеров (ну, не считая настройки размерности окрестности). Лично мне бы эти методы -  если картинка уже переведена в массив координат точек -  первыми пришли в голову.

Comment: @CrazyElf сделал триангулирование(в пост добавил), ещё подсказали использовать scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components()

Comment: Вот, буквально из сегодняшней ленты feedly : https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/k-means-clustering-and-transfer-learning-for-image-classification/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+AnalyticsVidhya+%28Analytics+Vidhya%29    К-means кластеризация при работе с картинками типа ваших..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно решение состоит в триангуляции набора точек, удалении треугольников с длинными ребрами и поиска связных компонент графа.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import connected_components
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

coord = [[0.0789702838086786, 0.026726748654913795, -0.33899998664855957],
         [0.07952999876630526, 0.026726748654913795, -0.33899998664855957],
         [0.07985346391344544, 0.02664790970030836, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.08041152781569287, 0.02664790970030836, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.0809695917179403, 0.02664790970030836, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.0789702838086786, 0.026166138141604005, -0.33899998664855957],
         [0.07929540001119802, 0.026088952884101083, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.07961721410295897, 0.02601176762659816, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.08017362694982716, 0.02601176762659816, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.08049048073615488, 0.025934580068765693, -0.335999995470047],
         [0.0810452424784379, 0.025934580068765693, -0.335999995470047],
         [0.08160000422072093, 0.025934580068765693, -0.335999995470047],
         [0.07929540001119802, 0.025529996067893804, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.07961721410295897, 0.025454464507493394, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.08017362694982716, 0.025454464507493394, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.08049048073615488, 0.025378930696048088, -0.335999995470047],
         [0.0810452424784379, 0.025378930696048088, -0.335999995470047],
         [0.08160000422072093, 0.025378930696048088, -0.335999995470047],
         [0.025088755109876883, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.02564516795674507, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.02620158080361325, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.026757993650481437, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.02731440649734962, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.027870819344217805, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.02842723219108599, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.028983645037954173, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.02954005788482236, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.030096470731690545, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.030652883578558728, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.031209296425426913, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.0317657092722951, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.032322122119163285, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.032878534966031464, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03343494781289965, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.033991360659767836, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03454777350663602, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03510418635350421, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.035660599200372387, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03621701204724057, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03677342489410876, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.037329837740976944, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03788625058784513, -0.10439716224391743, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.02635707779177199, -0.10557733248619632, -0.33899998664855957],
         [0.026916792749398656, -0.10557733248619632, -0.33899998664855957],
         [0.027395457102187472, -0.10526589892460925, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.0279535210044349, -0.10526589892460925, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.028511584906682323, -0.10526589892460925, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.028983645037954173, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.02954005788482236, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.0301857766134246, -0.10526589892460925, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.030652883578558728, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.031209296425426913, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.0317657092722951, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.032322122119163285, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.032878534966031464, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03343494781289965, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.033991360659767836, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03454777350663602, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03510418635350421, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.035660599200372387, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03621701204724057, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03677342489410876, -0.10495446536302219, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.02635707779177199, -0.1061379429995061, -0.33899998664855957],
         [0.026916792749398656, -0.1061379429995061, -0.33899998664855957],
         [0.027395457102187472, -0.10582485574081653, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.0279535210044349, -0.10582485574081653, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.028511584906682323, -0.10582485574081653, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.028983645037954173, -0.10551176848212696, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.02954005788482236, -0.10551176848212696, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.0301857766134246, -0.10582485574081653, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.030652883578558728, -0.10551176848212696, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.031209296425426913, -0.10551176848212696, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.0317657092722951, -0.10551176848212696, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.032322122119163285, -0.10551176848212696, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.032878534966031464, -0.10551176848212696, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03343494781289965, -0.10551176848212696, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.033991360659767836, -0.10551176848212696, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03454777350663602, -0.10551176848212696, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03510418635350421, -0.10551176848212696, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.035660599200372387, -0.10551176848212696, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03621701204724057, -0.10551176848212696, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03677342489410876, -0.10551176848212696, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.030743840515672024, -0.10638381255702381, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.03130190441791945, -0.10638381255702381, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.031859968320166875, -0.10638381255702381, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.0324180322224143, -0.10638381255702381, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.03297609612466172, -0.10638381255702381, -0.33799999952316284],
         [0.03343494781289965, -0.10606907160123173, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.033991360659767836, -0.10606907160123173, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03454777350663602, -0.10606907160123173, -0.3370000123977661],
         [0.03510418635350421, -0.10606907160123173, -0.3370000123977661]]
coord = np.array(coord)
points = coord[:, :2]
x = points[:, 0]
y = points[:, 1]
triang = Triangulation(points[:, 0], points[:, 1])  # триангуляция набора точек

max_radius = 0.02  # максимальное расстояние, cut off
triangles = triang.triangles
xtri = x[triangles] - np.roll(x[triangles], 1, axis=1)
ytri = y[triangles] - np.roll(y[triangles], 1, axis=1)
# максимальная длина стороны треугольника
maxi = np.max(np.sqrt(xtri**2 + ytri**2), axis=1)
triang.set_mask(maxi > max_radius)  # фильтрация треугольников по длине стороны
num_nodes = np.max(triang.edges)+1  # число вершин
graph = csr_matrix((np.ones(triang.edges.shape[0]), (
    triang.edges[:, 0], triang.edges[:, 1])), shape=(num_nodes, num_nodes))
n, labels = connected_components(graph.toarray(), directed=False)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_aspect('equal')

for i in range(n):
    ax1.scatter(coord[labels == i, 0], coord[labels == i, 1], s=0.5)
    print(f'Компонент {i}: ')
    print(coord[labels == i])
plt.show()
```

[image: пример кластеризации]